# What's the use for anonymous functions in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, function, anonymous

I came across them, but I have yet to see why I should use them. Could someone explain it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is comfortably to use in closures, when you need not name for this function. I. e. this way:

```
var myFunc : Function = function() : void {trace("Hello world!");}
doSomething(myFunc);
```

or this:

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,
    function(e : MouseEvent) : void
    {
        // doSomething
    });
```

You do not have to use them, but you may if it is easier.

Comment: The last example should never be used, since you cannot remove the eventlistener, which can cause memory leaks.

Comment: @mark you can still remove the listener inside the function e.currentTarget.remove...... However, outside of that function there is no way to remove it.

Comment: @mark, @The_asMan or indeed by using `button.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, arguments.callee)`

Answer (score 4):

Essentially, an anonymous function allows you to create very fine-grained variations to behavior, without having to create a subclass, or to encapsulate what would otherwise have to be a complex switch statement into a short, clean method block: Where you would have to make a lot of decisions based on state, you can now simply **assign a function to perform a certain task at runtime**.  Think of it like any variable - only this special kind of variable doesn't have a *value*, but a *behavior*.

The standard example for this is event listeners, but you can also apply this to any other functionality you desire.

You can find out about anonymous functions [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/simplicity/2007/10/post.html), and subsequently learn about the concept of [closures at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29).  Admittedly, the Wikipedia source is a bit heavy with technical terms, but Martin Fowler also has a quite [readable blog post](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/Closure.html) on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

At the risk of oversimplifying, you can think of anonymous functions as "throwaway" functions that you need to create at runtime. Here's an example of where might you use one:

Imagine you have some buttons on screen for changing colors and the handler for each of them looks like this (pseudocode, please overlook syntax errors):

```
private function redBtnHandler(): void {
  GlobalBrush.setColor(0xff0000);
}
private function greenBtnHandler(): void {
  GlobalBrush.setColor(0x00ff00);
}
private function blueBtnHandler(): void {
  GlobalBrush.setColor(0x0000ff);
}
...
redBtn.setClickHandler(redBtnHandler);
greenBtn.setClickHandler(greenBtnHandler);
blueBtn.setClickHandler(blueBtnHandler);
...
```

It's painful to create a bunch of these, not to mention hard-to-edit later on.

Instead, you'd use a "function factory" to generate handlers, like so:

```
private function generateBtnHandler(rgb:uint): Function {
  var btnHandler:Function = function(): void {
    GlobalBrush.setColor(rgb);
  }
  return btnHandler;
}
redBtn.setClickHandler(generateBtnHandler(0xff0000));
greenBtn.setClickHandler(generateBtnHandler(0x00ff00));
blueBtn.setClickHandler(generateBtnHandler(0x0000ff));
```

In "set-and-forget" situations like the above, these are extremely handy.

Hope the above example helped make it clear why anyone would use these things.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/functions.html
http://www.alanmacdougall.com/blog/post/3/

Or

An anonymous function is defined like this:

```
bar = function(param1, param2, etc) {
    // do stuff here      
}
```

Anonymous functions are interesting beasts. Unlike named functions, when you create an anonymous function there is no way to reference the function via code. We can get around this with function literals.

When the function is created it returns a reference to itself. In the example above, we set a variable "bar" to reference the anonymous function we create.

Now, whenever bar is called, the anonymous function that it references will execute. Unlike named functions, anonymous functions cannot be forward referenced. If I make a call to bar before I set bar to reference the function, the call will fail.

When creating an anonymous recursive function, the function can reference itself by using the arguments.callee property. Consider this example:

```
    // classic factorial recursion example
    factorial = function(n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
            return n;
    } else {
            return n*arguments.callee(n-1);  // call ourself to recurse
    }
 }
```

Note that in the above example, we can replace arguments.callee with factorial and the example will still work. However, there are times in which we don't have a variable to call the function with. In those cases, arguments.callee is the only solution. An example of this might be passing an anonymous function as a parameter to another function.

Function literals can define functions in any timeline/object, provided the path exists at the time of definition. For instance, to create a function inside of an object, we have to use a function literal like this:

```
   obj = new Object();
   obj.foo = function() {
      return "bar";
   }

   trace(obj.foo());  // bar
```